# Why do I have to perform a hot restart to see the changes in my database in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I'm learning Flutter and I'm trying to use the SQFLite package to persist data on the device. Everything works perfect but there's one problem, every time I add a new element or I upgrade it, I need to restart my app to see the changes and I don't know why, there are no errors or anything.
I uploaded it to github so you can try it, maybe is something in my emulator or something I dont know.
https://github.com/Rodrigogzmn6/sql_demo

or you can see part of the complete project here

Home Page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sql_demo/models/product.dart';
import 'package:sql_demo/pages/add_product_page.dart';
import 'package:sql_demo/pages/update_product_page.dart';
import 'package:sql_demo/pages/view_product_page.dart';
import 'package:sql_demo/services/dbhelper.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  DbHelper helper;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    helper = DbHelper();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: helper.getProducts(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Product product = Product.fromMap(snapshot.data[index]);
                  return ListTile(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    title: Text(
                        '${product.name} - \$${(product.price).toString()}'),
                    subtitle: Text(product.description),
                    trailing: Column(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.delete,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  helper.deleteProduct(product.id);
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.edit,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => UpdateProductPage(
                                            product: product,
                                          )),
                                );
                              }),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ProductDetailsPage(
                                    product: product,
                                  )));
                    },
                  );
                });
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddProductPage()));
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Creating Item page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sql_demo/models/product.dart';
import 'package:sql_demo/services/dbhelper.dart';

class AddProductPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddProductPageState createState() => _AddProductPageState();
}

class _AddProductPageState extends State<AddProductPage> {
  String name, description;
  num price;
  DbHelper helper;

  //Instantiate Helper
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    helper = DbHelper();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add new product"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter product name',
              labelText: 'Product name',
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                name = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter product description',
              labelText: 'Product description',
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                description = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16),
          TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter product price',
              labelText: 'Product price',
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                price = double.parse(value);
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Save'),
            onPressed: () {
              Product product = Product({
                'name': name,
                'description': description,
                'price': price,
              });
              setState(() {
                helper.createProduct(product);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Database operations

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:sql_demo/models/product.dart';

class DbHelper {
  //Creates a singleton class (it only creates once)
  static final DbHelper _singleton = DbHelper._internal();
  factory DbHelper() => _singleton;
  DbHelper._internal();

  //Creating an object of type database
  static Database _database;

  //Initializing or creating the database named mydb.db
  //Creating a products table with necessary fields
  Future<Database> initDatabase() async {
    //If this class was never instaciated, we will execute this method, otherwise return
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'mydb.db');
    _database = await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (Database db, int v) async {
        await db.execute(
            'CREATE TABLE Products (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, description TEXT, price REAL)');
      },
    );
    return _database;
  }

  //Select all products
  Future<List> getProducts() async {
    Database db = await initDatabase();
    return await db.query('Products');
  }

  //Create new product
  Future<int> createProduct(Product product) async {
    Database db = await initDatabase();
    print('Product added');
    return await db.insert(
      'Products',
      product.toMap(),
    );
  }

  //Update product
  Future<int> updateProduct(Product product) async {
    Database db = await initDatabase();
    return await db.update(
      'Products',
      product.toMap(),
      where: 'id=?',
      whereArgs: [product.id],
    );
  }

  //Delete a product
  Future<int> deleteProduct(int productID) async {
    Database db = await initDatabase();
    return await db.delete('Products', where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [productID]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can `await Navigator.push` to `AddProductPage` and then call `setState(() {});` 
code snippet

```
onPressed: () async {
        await Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddProductPage()));

        setState(() {});
      }),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class Product {
  int _id;
  String _name;
  String _description;
  double _price;

  //Getters because the attributes are private
  int get id => _id;
  String get name => _name;
  String get description => _description;
  double get price => _price;

  //Constructor
  Product(dynamic obj) {
    _id = obj['id'];
    _name = obj['name'];
    _description = obj['description'];
    _price = obj['price'];
  }

  //Named objet (takes a Map as parameter)
  Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    _id = data['id'];
    _name = data['name'];
    _description = data['description'];
    _price = data['price'];
  }

  //Method that converts the object into a map

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': _id,
      'name': _name,
      'description': _description,
      'price': _price,
    };
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  DbHelper helper;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    helper = DbHelper();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: helper.getProducts(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Product product = Product.fromMap(snapshot.data[index]);
                  return ListTile(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    title: Text(
                        '${product.name} - \$${(product.price).toString()}'),
                    subtitle: Text(product.description),
                    trailing: Column(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.delete,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  helper.deleteProduct(product.id);
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.edit,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                /*Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => UpdateProductPage(
                                        product: product,
                                      )),
                                );*/
                              }),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      /*Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ProductDetailsPage(
                                product: product,
                              )));*/
                    },
                  );
                });
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () async {
            await Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddProductPage()));

            setState(() {});
          }),
    );
  }
}

class AddProductPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddProductPageState createState() => _AddProductPageState();
}

class _AddProductPageState extends State<AddProductPage> {
  String name, description;
  num price;
  DbHelper helper;

  //Instantiate Helper
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    helper = DbHelper();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add new product"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter product name',
              labelText: 'Product name',
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                name = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter product description',
              labelText: 'Product description',
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                description = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16),
          TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter product price',
              labelText: 'Product price',
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                price = double.parse(value);
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Save'),
            onPressed: () {
              Product product = Product({
                'name': name,
                'description': description,
                'price': price,
              });
              setState(() {
                helper.createProduct(product);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DbHelper {
  //Creates a singleton class (it only creates once)
  static final DbHelper _singleton = DbHelper._internal();
  factory DbHelper() => _singleton;
  DbHelper._internal();

  //Creating an object of type database
  static Database _database;

  //Initializing or creating the database named mydb.db
  //Creating a products table with necessary fields
  Future<Database> initDatabase() async {
    //If this class was never instaciated, we will execute this method, otherwise return
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'mydb.db');
    _database = await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (Database db, int v) async {
        await db.execute(
            'CREATE TABLE Products (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, description TEXT, price REAL)');
      },
    );
    return _database;
  }

  //Select all products
  Future<List> getProducts() async {
    Database db = await initDatabase();
    return await db.query('Products');
  }

  //Create new product
  Future<int> createProduct(Product product) async {
    Database db = await initDatabase();
    print('Product added');
    return await db.insert(
      'Products',
      product.toMap(),
    );
  }

  //Update product
  Future<int> updateProduct(Product product) async {
    Database db = await initDatabase();
    return await db.update(
      'Products',
      product.toMap(),
      where: 'id=?',
      whereArgs: [product.id],
    );
  }

  //Delete a product
  Future<int> deleteProduct(int productID) async {
    Database db = await initDatabase();
    return await db.delete('Products', where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [productID]);
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You saved my life!! It totally works, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**Hot reload**: Hot reload feature quickly compile the newly added code in our file and sent the code to Dart Virtual Machine. If you are using States in your application then Hot Reload preservers the States so they will not update on Hot Reload our set to their default values.

And, `initState()` does not rebuild after hot reload as its state is preserved. So, you have to perform hot restart to see database changes:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    helper = DbHelper();
  }
```

When stateful widget is build, you have `helper`, but after you hot reload, the helper will be same as `initState` only called hot restart or you launch the widget. So, `helper` variable is preserved. Hence, you have to hot restart.

Links that might help you: [Understanding Flutter hot reload and hot restart the simplest way](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/understanding-flutter-hot-reload-and-hot-restart-the-simplest-way) | [Refs](https://flutter-examples.com/difference-between-hot-reload-and-hot-restart-in-flutter-dart/)